# I can't remove an manage_file field image

Tags: forms, files

I have the next managed_file field:

```
$form['portada_field']['imagen_portada'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Imagen'),
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#description' => t('Extensiones permitidas: gif png jpg jpeg'),
            '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
            '#upload_location' => 'public://articulos/portada',
            '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
            '#status' => FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
            '#progress_message' => 'One moment while we save your file...',
                '#states' => array(
                    'visible' => array(
                      ':input[name="checkbox_imagen"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
                    ),
                ),
         );
```

After upload an image, If I want to remove the image I can't do it, it appears again

How I can remove it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use db query to remove the entry

```
  $mydir =  variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');
  $filename = $mydir .$file_directory. $filename;
  unlink($filename);
  db_delete('file_managed')
      ->condition('filename', $filename)
      ->execute();
  $FileStatus = "The file has been removed - ".$filename;
```

Get the public directory path and delete the file from file_managed table

This will make your work easy.